# How to add permissions to an external library in android?

Tags: android

I want to use a library in my project. But I do not want this library to have permissions to access files, database or download something from the network in my application. How can I achieve my aim?

The library is provided by others, I need to use some function in it, but I do not want it to have permission to hack my app. Maybe I need something like a sandbox to run this library, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are embedding the library (JAR or .so) in your app, then you cannot limit its access.  The library code is running in the context of your app and is effectively "linked" with your code.  It has access to anything your app's process does since it is running within it.

If you want separation, you would need to isolate the library into another APK package and interface with that package via binder or `Intent`.  Even then, you would need to ensure the other package was not using shared user IDs (which is the default) and you would probably want to sign it with a different key.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Comment: Please also help me for this case. I would like to know that If a dependency does not declare Contact permission in manifest file, can it access to Contacts if user approve this permission from my app?